# React useEffect: Why is my value undefined initially?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to setup an onKeyPress event listener and I'm confused as to why the initial value is undefined and *then* the value I want. The data is added on mount (see `x` in console). Why am I unable to immediately capture it and instead get an initial `undefined`, especially since it clearly already exists in state?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log('x', multipleChoice);       <-- logs the array of objects

    const handleKeyPress = ({ key }) => {
      const index = Number(key) - 1;
      if (key === '1') {
        console.log(multipleChoice[index]);    <-- logs undefined, then logs object
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => handleKeyPress(e));

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', (e) => handleKeyPress(e));
    };
  }, [allCards, currentCard, multipleChoice]);
```

---

**LocalState**

```
  const [currentCard, setCard] = useState(0);
  const [multipleChoice, setMultipleChoice] = useState([]);

// allCards is passed as a prop on page load from the parent
```

When the user guesses an answer correctly the currentCard is incremented by 1

**UseEffect that sets multipleChoice**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const generateMultipleChoice = (words: Word[]) => {
      const possibleAnswers = words.reduce(
        (accum: Word[]) => {
          while (accum.length < 4) {
            // randomly select words from pool
            const index = getRandomInt(0, allCards.length - 1);
            const randomWord = allCards[index];
            // verify current hand doesn't already have that word
            if (!accum.includes(randomWord)) {
              accum.push(randomWord);
            }
          }
          return accum;
        },
        // default with the current card already in the hand
        [allCards[currentCard]]
      );
      // return the hand with the matching card and (3) other cards from pool
      return possibleAnswers;
    };

    const shuffledCards = shuffle(generateMultipleChoice(allCards));

    setMultipleChoice(shuffledCards);
  }, [allCards, currentCard]);
```

**screenshot of console**
[image]

Comment: Possibly a different issue, but you're adding a new event listener every time the effect runs and you're never removing them. Every time a dependency changes you add another. You should return a function that removes the listener.

Comment: hey @rayhatfield, I actually _just_ added that in my code. It was brought up in this resource that I'm currently referencing: https://usehooks.com/useKeyPress/

Comment: What is the value of `multipleChoice` when the component mounts? Does it ever change? Can you update your question to include all relevant component code? I.E the dependencies and any code updating them.

Comment: Where does `multipleChoice` come from? What do you mean by "the data is added on mount"?

Comment: @rayhatfield updated, I had a console log at the start of the effect that logs the empty array and populated array (the "x" console log)  as soon as the page refreshes / component mounts. Or, perhaps when the dependency updates ... which happens on mount.

Comment: Your initial `multipleChoice` state is an empty array, so accessing *any* index results in undefined. All effect hooks will run at least once on component mount. The console log in the effect callback body would execute, but I don't think the log in the `handleKeyPress` handler should execute unless you press a key *before* the effect runs again shortly after mount and is updated by the other effect (*and log again shortly after with another key press*).

Comment: @DrewReese yeah that makes sense, and the log within the `handleKeyPress` does not run unless clicked. What's strange to me though is why if I click that button is logs undefined & the data. Why wouldnt it just return one or the other instead of both on one click?

Comment: Is it possible to create a live version of this code in a *running* codesandbox that we can run and debug?

Comment: @DrewReese thats a good question, i've never setup one of those environments before. When i circle back around to resolving this issue, if I'm not able to resolve it, i'll go ahead and create one and post you.

Comment: [codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/) has a react template that does all the heavy lifting for you; you need only add the extra dependencies (if any) and only the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce your issue. Sometimes when distilling your code down to a minimal example the cause for the issue becomes more apparent and fixable.

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```js
// initial state
const [multipleChoice, setMultipleChoice] = useState([]);

// therefore, initially, if index is any Number
console.log(multipleChoice[index])  // undefined
```

The object is returned, only until the calculation is finished...

```js
useEffect(() => {
   // ...
   // this has to run before `multipleChoice` is updated to return that object 
   const shuffledCards = shuffle(generateMultipleChoice(allCards));

   setMultipleChoice(shuffledCards);
}, [allCards, currentCard]);
```